# can I get $scope in custom directive for input field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using [angular-payment](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments) to implement payment system. Now what I want is to allow only `Visa` and `MasterCard`. I am using `Custom Directive` for that.

Here is the code:

```
<form class="col-xs-12 row" name="addCardForm" novalidate data-ng-hide = buyCreditsCtrl.useSavedCard>
<fieldset data-ng-disabled="buyCreditsCtrl.buyCreditsStep === buyCreditsCtrl.VERIFYING_CARD">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group"
             required=""
             data-ng-class="{'has-error':addCardForm.holderName.$dirty && addCardForm.holderName.$invalid}">
            <label for="paymenstCardHolder">Card Holder's Name</label>
            <input id="paymenstCardHolder"
                   type="text"
                   required=""
                   name="holderName"
                   data-ng-model="buyCreditsCtrl.cardDetails.name"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Card Holder's Name"
                    />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"
             data-ng-class="{'has-error':addCardForm.card.$dirty && addCardForm.card.$invalid}">
            <label for="paymentsCard">Card Number</label>
            <input id="paymentsCard"
                   required=""
                   type="text"
                   data-ng-model="buyCreditsCtrl.cardDetails.number"
                   data-payments-type-model="buyCreditsCtrl.cardDetails.type"
                   data-payments-validate="card"
                   name="card"
                   class="form-control"
                   data-payments-format="card"
                   regex-validate = "sdsdfsdf"
                   placeholder="Card Number" />
        </div>
```

so basically for `input id ='paymentCard` I want to create a `custom directive` so that I can show an error message when card other than Visa and MasterCard are used. I want access to `$scope.type` in my custom directive to perform the validation.

Comment: Why do you need directive for this? You can just use some ngShow, etc.

Comment: If you don't isolate scope, the directive will have access to the scope of the parent controller. If you isolate scope, just pass the type to the directive scope.